# ResolvePackageNotFound: Importing env from .yml file

Tags: anaconda3, virtual-environment

I want to import an environment from github, but for some reason, the error ResolvePackageNotFound popped up.

Command: `conda env create -f bullseye.yml`

Following message appears after pressing ENTER:

```
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

ResolvePackageNotFound:
  - gcc_linux-64
  - samtools=1.12
  - htslib=1.12
  - bedtools=2.30.0
```

This is the .yml file I am trying to import from:

```
name: Bullseye
channels:
 - conda-forge
 - bioconda
dependencies:
 - gcc_linux-64
 - perl-bioperl=1.7.2
 - htslib=1.12
 - samtools=1.12
 - bedtools=2.30.0
```

Thank you for any help!